# price display of configurable products change to 10 when select color in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I'm using magento 1.9.1 for my website shop.
I have many configurable products with several color that i created in the admin panel.

now in frontend, when i select the colors of the configurable product with (for example: price 1000), the price change into (10) instead of remaining in (1000).
I use no extension, except ET extension.
I also found these links, but couldn't find the solution:

http://k2xl.com/wordpress/custom-options-broken-in-magento-1-7-heres-the-fix/

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110307/magento-2-configurable-product-showing-0-price-if-we-change-locale-to-persian

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102577/product-page-pricing-is-0-after-upgrading-to-magento-1-9-2-3-from-1-9-1-1

http://support.etwebsolutions.com/issues/1558

also, in this file: **app/design/[your package]/[yourtheme]/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml** i didn't find this line of code: **price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()]);**

I will appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that a .xml file caused this problem!
in /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/[yourLanguage].xml file and this piece of code:

```
<currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
        <currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormat type="standard">
                <pattern>‎#,##0.00   ¤</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
            <currencyFormat type="accounting">
                <pattern>‎#,##0.00   ¤;‎(#,##0.00   ¤)</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
        </currencyFormatLength>
        <unitPattern count="one">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
        <unitPattern count="other">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
    </currencyFormats>
```

Luckily! when i wanted to change the alignment of currency symbol and the price, i change the position of '¤' from left to right.
after clearing the cache, problem of price display get solved!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
hope this is helpful for anyone else...